# Webpage not found javascript error

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to javascript and was practicing when i came accross this error where my web browser can't find the html document when the location variable is inside the `<script</script` tags

```
<script>
<!--

    var location = "Syrdsase va";
    var name = "bob sixlet";
    var age = 14;

    document.write(name + ", " + age + location);

//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `location` object which when assigned to, changes the location of the page:

```
location = 'http://www.google.com'; // goes to Google homepage
```

Usually, to avoid confusion, it is usually referred to using `window.location`, but since `window` is simply the global object, reassigning `location` will make the page go to the URL that is the value of the string.

To solve the issue, simply rename the variable:

```
var myLocation = "Syrdsase va";

var name = "bob sixlet";

var age = 14;

document.write(name + ", " + age + myLocation);
```

Comment: Alright that seemed to work. Are there any other names i should be cautious of using when naming variables?

Comment: @HeyItsProdigy: there are numerous of them (such as `navigator`, `document`, etc.).  Calling something like `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(window)` on an empty page should show almost all of the ones already assigned.  Also, you should be aware of JavaScript's reserved words: [official specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.6.1)

Answer (score 2):

juste don't use location as a variable it will redirect you to a new page. change your variale's name and it will work

some reserved variables in js
http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_reserved_words.cfm